# Socat sends the response at the end and not in the right order

Tags: c, debugging, socat

I am trying to run a program as a server with socat, It is a very simple program but I don't receive the data in the right order. I only receive the server response when I have sent the data and not in the correct order.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buff[64];
    char t[10];
    printf("Welcome\n");
    gets(t);
    printf(t);
    printf("\n");
    gets(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run with socat:

Server:

```
$ socat -v tcp-listen:4444,reuseaddr,fork exec:"./test"
> 2018/05/24 10:33:42.102445  length=2 from=0 to=1
a
> 2018/05/24 10:33:42.582042  length=2 from=2 to=3
a
< 2018/05/24 10:33:42.583721  length=10 from=0 to=9
Welcome
a
$ socat -v tcp-listen:4444,reuseaddr,fork exec:"./leak"
> 2018/05/24 10:39:02.551405  length=7 from=0 to=6
FOOBAR
> 2018/05/24 10:39:03.511667  length=5 from=7 to=11
LALA
< 2018/05/24 10:39:03.512021  length=15 from=0 to=14
Welcome
FOOBAR
```

Client:

```
$ nc 192.168.2.230 4444
FOOBAR             
LALA
Welcome
FOOBAR
```

Obviously when I run as a program it works correctly.

```
$ ./test 
Welcome
FOOBAR
FOOBAR
:)
```

What could be happening? have I missed any arguments?

**SOLUTION**

Add `setbuf(stdout, 0)`; before first printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    setbuf(stdout, 0);
    char buff[64];
    char t[10];
    printf("Welcome\n");
    gets(t);
    printf(t);
    printf("\n");
    gets(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side remark 1: `gets(t);` is unsafe due to potential buffer overflow; use `fgets(t, sizeof(t), stdin);` instead. `gets(buff);` is also unsafe for the same reason. Side remark 2: `printf(t)` is unsafe due to untrusted data contents; use `printf("%s", t);` instead, or use `printf("%s\n", t);` to combine it with the `printf("\n");`.

Comment: Hehe, that's the purpose of this example. Leak the canary and libc thought format string vulnerability then exploit the buffer overflow. My question is other.

Comment: Try calling `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` calls, or call `setlinebuf(stdout);` before the first `printf` to set the `stdout` stream to line-buffered mode.

Comment: Adding setbuf(stdout, 0); before first prinf It works correctly. Thanks